# Symbolic link of for my user, doesn't work for root

Tags: filesystems, files, fedora

I am experimenting with the following scheme in order to share common data among different distributions.

In Fedora I have created a symbolic link `/home` pointing to:

```
/run/media/arun/754ef10a-3f82-4c0b-bde4-a119f7cc472c/Fedora/
```

In BackTrack I have `/home` pointing to

```
/run/media/arun/754ef10a-3f82-4c0b-bde4-a119f7cc472c/BT-Linux/
```

And right now I am doing the same for OpenSuSE 12.3.

The `/home` on each distro is a symbolic link to its respective directory on the partition. ie: Fedora, BT-Linux, SuSE.

Each of these have `Documents`, `Downloads` and `Videos` folders that are again symbolic links to independent directories (not in `/run/media/...../Fedora` or `BT-Linux` or `Suse`),  so I can access those directories right from the `/home` directory.

The problem is that although the link is alive in my user account `arun`,
the symbolic link is broken when I login as `root`.

It is working fine as a normal user but not as `root`.

I know the fact that `root` will have its own set of `Documents`, `Desktop`, `Videos` folders, all which needs to be linked too but, the symbolic link `/home` itself is broken.

What could be the cause of this issue?

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.9.5-301.fc19.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 11 19:39:38 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: soory for the indentation... but where i mention directories... i mean the /home is pointing to /run/media/..../ Fedora or BT-Linux or SuSE.

Comment: I made rather invasive changes to your question, especially your title. Please correct or rollback if I misunderstood what you're asking - the original title didn't seem to match your actual problem at all. (You can rollback by going to the revision history and clicking on the "rollback" link for the version you want to rollback to.)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using a [removable disk mountpoint](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html/Release_Notes/sect-Release_Notes-Changes_for_Desktop.html#id554181) for the /home symlink, which is automatically set up when you log in with the user 'arun', and it's a most likely a FUSE mountpoint.  If you're trying to access the mountpoint from root when your user 'arun' isn't logged in, it hasn't been automounted yet.  [FUSE, unless set up to allow otherwise, restricts permission from root](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FAQ#Why_don.27t_other_users_have_access_to_the_mounted_filesystem.3F), so even if 'arun' is logged in, only the user wouldn be allowed access.

If you really want to use this drive for home, set it up in /etc/fstab.  However, it won't work as an automounted removable drive there.

Comment: I didnt fully understand your answer as i myself am not well versed with the intricacies of the FS , this might be a plausible answer.

Answer (score 0):

well, i got around this problem

in all its simplicity, the objective was to share /home between multiple distributions.

1. what i did was had a partition, and a Directory named OpenSuSE mounted at **/home** in openSuSE12.3 and then on that partition i created 2 more directories namely Fedora and BT-Linux and had a directory named 'arun' inside each one of them.
2. While installing Fedora19 and BTlinux i 'removed' the /home diectory and created a symbolic link called 'home' in the RootFS that linked to

**/run/media/arun/my_disk_part/Fedora**

**/run/media/arun/my_disk_part/BT-Linux**

respectively.....

Now the complexities begin....

my obejective was to share the files in openSuSE among Distributions
so inside

**/run/media/arun/my_disk_part/Fedora/**
and
**/run/media/arun/my_disk_part/BT-Linux **

i had Symlinks named Documents, Downloads, Pictures and all pointing to

**/run/media/arun/my_disk_part/OpenSuSE/Documents**

**/run/media/arun/my_disk_part/OpenSuSE/Downloads**

**/run/media/arun/my_disk_part/OpenSuSE/Pictures**

---done---

now i had my movies, videos, and pictures shared
but the Application settings like the "Keyring Passwords", "Background","Bash.rc"
which shall be specific for each distribution remained untouched...

I think this was a Lengthy solution and the same could have been achieved in a easier way.

One more thing, Permissions have to be changed for the Symlinks, i created them as SU so they were accessible from the 'root' account and not from other accounts.

a **chmod** on those symlinks did the job for me.

anybody having an easier solution is welcome to share it, or correct me if i have done something wrong here. :)

Comment: again, the symlinks have to be created for each and every account with which the data need to be shared, and even for root.